# Why Frucht's Theorem is only true for Finite Groups?

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group, cayley-graphs, topological-graph-theory

The statement of the Frucht's Theorem as follows:
"Every Finite Group is Automorphism Group of some graph."
The proof involves a result that the group of color preserving Automorphisms of a Cayley Color Graph of a finite group is isomorphic to the group itself.

I am confused how to use the condition of 'finite group' in the proof of above results.
I suspect that the second result is true for all groups and not necessarily for finite groups. And in that case Frucht's Theorem should be true for all Groups. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's true for every group, Frucht was only able to prove it for finite groups. The proof for infinite groups is actually a lot harder.

You can find it right here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01319053

(you can find it on sci hub)